# Copied solr data/index but it's not showing

Tags: solr

I have an old core and a new one in a new location. I copied over the entire data folder from the old core into the new one. For some reason, I can't get it to actually work though (the Master is obviously huge, but there should be 3000+ docs, not 4). I tried reindexing from within the application we're using (Omeka) but that also failed. Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to re-create the core and index from scratch. I copied over the conf files from the old core and then re-indexed and everything ran smoothly. So when all else fails, re-create and re-index!